# x is not a function - why will this function not work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a hyphenated string from a global variable - title. I am having trouble understanding why this function will not work and the other one will but it alters the global variable.

When I do not assign the String and Array methods to variables I received the "x" is not a function error. When I do assign them to variable, the functions produces the correct output but modifies the global variable. 
Receive "x" is not a function error:

```
function urlSlug(title) {
  title.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  title.filter(el => {return el});
  title.join("-");
  return title;

}
```

Alters global variable:

```
function urlSlug(title) {
    var arr = title;
    var arr1 = arr.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var filtered = arr1.filter(el => {return el});
    var arr2 = filtered.join("-");
    console.log(arr2);
    return arr2;
}
```

Comment: What is the `x` that isn't a function? You never define or use such a variable in your code

Comment: An alternative to split/join is a `replace`: `title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'-')`

Comment: My glass ball tells me, he is getting "title.filter is not a function", because `title` is a string, and he didn't assign the result of `split` to `title`.

Comment: Functions like `split()`, `join()` and `filter()` don't modify what they were called on, they return new arrays and strings.

Comment: BTW, `el => { return el}` can be just `el => el`

Comment: You are using the functions correctly in your second example - functions like `filter` and `split` return new objects rather than manipulate the existing ones. However, you mention that a global variable is being altered: which global variables specifically are being altered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function urlSlug(title) {
  //  split() return a new array; don't modify variable in place.
  title.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  title.filter(el => {return el}); // Consequently, title is not an array but a string. Filter is not defined. So it throws an error
  title.join("-");
  return title;
}
```

That's why : TypeError: title.filter is not a function. The function returns then nothing.

A way to make this work is :

```js
function urlSlug(title) {
  let splitted = title.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  splitted = splitted.filter(el => el);
  return title.join("-");
}
```

Or in one line :

```js
function urlSlug(title) {
  return title.split(" ").filter(el=>el).join("-");
}
```